# Get all the xml childname

Tags: c#, xml

I have this code and I found this on internet.

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

```
        doc.LoadXml("<book ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
                    "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
                    "<price>19.95</price>" +
                    "</book>");

        XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;

        //Display the contents of the child nodes.
        if (root.HasChildNodes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                //inner text contains the value of the childnode
                Console.WriteLine(root.ChildNodes[i].Name);
            }
        }
```

It does work, but when I load the `XML` file from the disk it doesn't give output. Why?

```
string xmlText = File.ReadAllText("Filename");

doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
```

Comment: and can someone explain to me the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Load` method if you have file path.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("filepath");
```

Comment: i already tried that but the output is still the same. no output

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("yourfile.xml"));//Load file from disk
var NodeNames = doc.Descendants("book").Elements().Select(x => x.Name.LocalName).ToList();
```

You will have to specify the `path` of folder if your file resides `inside folder`.